# What does the "x time ago" mean in the front page's sidebar chat area?

Tags: support, chat

In the sidebar of some sites, there are links to chatrooms. Underneath the name of each chatroom is a user's name. Beside this is a time.

[image: pointing out the above]

While the name seems to match the avatar on the left, it's clear this time is not the time of the last message posted unless there's some crazy caching going on, and I can't think of any other useful thing it could be. Similar times also pop up on hover for each other avatar. So what is it?

Comment: It's the time of the last message posted, with caching. I think.

Answer (score 3):

It is the time of the last message (and the hover over each gravatar is the last time that person talked). I'm not sure what time you saw that seemed wrong, but I just checked The Bridge on Gaming's homepage and it matched up within about a minute